# Tweening large sprites with TweenMax (AS3)

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, gsap

I'm trying to tween a Sprite's alpha to 1 using Greensock's TweenMax. cacheAsBitmap has been set to *true*. The Sprite fades alright at 800x600 (although you can already tell it's starting to lag), but when I set the dimensions of the Sprite to 1440x1080, the tween is significantly choppier.

The framerate drops from a consistent 24 to 11.1 when I try to tween, and CPU usage jumps from ~6% to 164%.

*DisplayList Rendering before, during, and after the tween:*

[image: DisplayList Rendering before, during, and after the tween]

*Top Activities:*

[image: Top Activities]

Any tips on how I can get a smoother result?

Comment: TweenMax can tween easily a 1440x1080 sprite without any fps drop. The problem you are having doesn't come from TweenMax but from what's in the sprite (a ton a vector graphics?) or what's running/displaying at the same time.

Comment: It does contain quite a few vector graphics. Shouldn't cacheAsBitmap flatten them, though?

Comment: only if it's a single frame clip

Comment: it would kinda flatten it depending on what you do with the object but for alpha not really. You can easily see it by switching between cacheAsBitmap true and false and see if you notice a difference. Better is to draw the object into a bitmap, tween that, then restore the original is need be.

Comment: Converting my Sprite to a Bitmap definitely helped performance - I'll go from here. Thanks @BotMaster